# Как мне сделать так, чтобы метод вызывался с задержкой?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Ребят, подскажите как решить проблему.

Мне нужно чтобы этот метод вызывался только через 2 секунды, и вызовы не ставились в очередь после каждого нажатого раза на ручку которая дергает запрос. Пытался сделать через setTimeout, но все равно запросы ставятся в очередь.

Т.е. нужно чтобы после того как была нажата кнопка прошло время и вывелся результат, и если человек еще раз нажмет кнопку то, только через 2 секунды был бы следующий вызов, но запросы не ставились бы в очередь, а был всего один.
Надеюсь я более менее объяснил.

Я читал, что можно сделать через debounce, но не понимаю как мне тогда построить логику..

```js
async getStatisctics_actions({commit}) {
  try {
    const url = '/recStructs'
    const options = {
      params: {
        currency: this.state.underlying,
        maturity: this.state.maturity,
        amount: this.state.amount,
        fut_hedge_flag: this.state.futHedgeFlag
      }
    }
    const response = await axios.get(url, options)
    commit('setFullData_mutations', response.data.data) // Получаем все графики
  } catch (error) {
    return error
  }
},
```

Comment: смотри в сторону `throttle` и `debounce`, в зависимости от того, какое поведение нужно

Comment: @Grundy предлагает лучшее решение, например библиотека `lodash` предлагает `throttle` и `debounce`. Если это кажется сложным, то как вариант создать в данных параметр который хранит время в миллисекундах когда попытка началась, и не дает начать вторую попытку пока текущее время не больше чем на 2000 миллисекунд.